# searching a file line by line for the first part of the line (python)

Tags: python

I have to search for a user input value but only in the first part of the line

```
def optionA():
    fixnum = input("What is the fixture number of the game?")
    with open("firesideFixtures.txt") as f:#open the file as "f"
          for line in f:#search each line
                 if str(fixnum) in line:#search each line for the user input
                       print(line)#print the line

optionA()
```

the problem is its printing every line with the fixture number in it. I need it to only print the one where the fixture number is the first character.
Here's the file:

```
   1,02/09/15,18:00,RNGesus,Ingsoc,Y,Ingsoc
   2,03/09/15,18:00,M'lady,Napoleon Wilson,Y,Napolean Wilson
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`startswith`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) then:

```
if line.startswith(str(fixnum)):
```

Comment: Python 2 would argue with you that fixnum isn't always a string ;)